# Facebook redirecting to a blank permission request page

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here's my app http://kunwar.fantoon.com/fb/, when I click on login link , it properly shows the login dialog box, once logged in it also shows the permission dialog box but when I click on the Allow button, it redirects to a blank page.

If for the second time I click on login button (this time I am already logged in to facebook and has granted all the permissions) then it will redirect to a blank page which has this url

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?api_key=142710779172144&app_id=142710779172144&display=popup&fbconnect=1&locale=en_US&method=permissions.request&next=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%23cb%3Df1afe28ad8e3884%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fkunwar.fantoon.com%252Ff104828fb358e68%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dpostmessage%26frame%3Df26d7271864ec8a%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&return_session=1&scope=email%2Cuser_location%2Cfriends_birthday%2Cfriends_likes%2Cfriends_photos%2Cfriends_location%2Cfriends_hometown%2Cfriends_work_history%2Cfriends_education_history&sdk=joey&session_version=3

Earlier this whole setup was working fine, but now all of a sudden this problem has appeared.

I am using javascript sdk to connect to facebook, its code is available at http://kunwar.fantoon.com/fb/js/fb_lib_common.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states on the blank page's console log: "Unsafe JavaScript attempt"

Set your channel file in `fb_lib_common.js`

```
   FB.init({
     appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
     status: true, 
     cookie: true,
     xfbml: true, 
     oauth: true,
     channelUrl: 'http://www.yourdomain.com/channel.html' 
   });
```

For http://www.yourdomain.com/channel.html, add the following,

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```